# On Android form panel textfield while entering key screen jumps up and down

Tags: sencha-touch

On Android form panel textfield while entering key screen jumps up and down, how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AndroidManifest.xml 
try adding **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** attribute to your activity's node.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```